# Kivy app permanently crashes with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: python, kivy

The following code permanently crashes with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
It seems that setting the text in the TextInput makes the application crash.

Can anyone confirm the error?

What does the error message mean?

I use threading, because I wanted the user to perform some actions on the screen and the application should wait for the result before going on.

Edit:
If there was something like a "goto" statement (o.k. sorry for that ;-)) I would like to jump to the line with comment `# further commands` and proceed there with the main flow.

```
import sys
import threading

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty


Builder.load_string("""

<MyWordRecorderScreen>:

    id: TheWordRecorderScreen
    my_text_input: TheTextInput
    my_record_button: TheRecordButton

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10 
        MyTextInput:
            id: TheTextInput
            my_screen: TheWordRecorderScreen
            # removing the following statement makes the app work but useless
            text: "Example"

        RecordButton:           
            id: TheRecordButton
            text: "Record"
            my_screen: TheWordRecorderScreen
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.15)

""")

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    pass

class RecordButton(Button):
    my_screen = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyWordRecorderScreen(Screen):
    my_record_button = ObjectProperty(None) 
    my_text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyScreenSequence():
    def __init__(self,my_screenmanager):
        self.sm=my_screenmanager

    def do_job(self):
        self.CurrentScreen = MyWordRecorderScreen()
        self.sm.switch_to(self.CurrentScreen)

def ApplicationFlow(MyScreenManager, *largs):   
    sm = MyScreenManager

    screen_terminated=threading.Condition()
    screen_terminated.acquire()
    # subroutine will use screen_terminated.notify_all() once result is available

    MSS=MyScreenSequence(my_screenmanager=sm)

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=MSS.do_job)
    t2.daemon = False
    t2.start()

    screen_terminated.wait()
    screen_terminated.release()

    # get result from subroutine

    # futher commands

    return


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        return self.sm
    def on_start(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=ApplicationFlow, args=[self.sm])
        t1.daemon = False
        t1.start()


def main(args):
    TestApp().run()
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Threads are not good for waiting for actions, what is your goal?

Comment: For one thing, your thread is doing user interface things that should only be done on the main thread. Not sure if that is THE problem, but try using Kivy's `Clock.schedule_once()` to do your `MSS.do_job()`, that will execute it on the main thread.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Basically I want the user to carry out some actions on the screen and when the results are available, they should be returned to the main "course of action" for further processing.

Comment: @John: Actually I tried Kivy's `Clock.schedule_once()`, however, I did not find a good solution to return to the ApplicationFlow after the result determined in MSS is available.

Comment: @John: In more detail: If the user presses a final button on the MSS screen, an `MSS.result` will be set. So far I did not manage to stop the ApplicationFlow until this result is available. A `while "result not available" loop`has the effect that the MSS screen is not even shown, probably as the main thread is busy. I was only successful, when I moved the ApplicationFlow to another thread ... but this does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I find it simpler to use `Thread.Event()`. Here is my version of your code that uses `Kivy.clock`:

```
import sys
import threading
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from functools import partial


Builder.load_string("""

<MyWordRecorderScreen>:

    id: TheWordRecorderScreen
    my_text_input: TheTextInput
    my_record_button: TheRecordButton

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10 
        MyTextInput:
            id: TheTextInput
            my_screen: TheWordRecorderScreen
            # removing the following statement makes the app work but useless
            text: "Example"

        RecordButton:           
            id: TheRecordButton
            text: "Record"
            my_screen: TheWordRecorderScreen
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.15)

""")

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    pass

class RecordButton(Button):
    my_screen = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyWordRecorderScreen(Screen):
    my_record_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    my_text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyScreenSequence():
    def __init__(self,my_screenmanager):
        self.sm=my_screenmanager

    def do_job(self, theEvent, dt):
        self.CurrentScreen = MyWordRecorderScreen()
        self.sm.switch_to(self.CurrentScreen)
        theEvent.set()

def ApplicationFlow(MyScreenManager, *largs):
    sm = MyScreenManager

    screen_terminated=threading.Event()
    # subroutine will use screen_terminated.set() once result is available

    MSS=MyScreenSequence(my_screenmanager=sm)

    Clock.schedule_once(partial(MSS.do_job, screen_terminated), 0)
    screen_terminated.wait()
    # get result from subroutine

    # futher commands

    return


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        return self.sm
    def on_start(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=ApplicationFlow, args=[self.sm])
        t1.daemon = False
        t1.start()


def main(args):
    TestApp().run()
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```